# SSHD connection ESTABLISHED in log but not showing up on last login

Tags: ssh, sshd

As the title suggest, i noticed that, by running/constantly watching/monitoring the output of:

```
lsof -i -P -n
```

that an ip different of my own local one, `ESTABLISHED` a connection on ssh.

This is on a remote server. I'm not too sure if it actually managed to login, but the output of the command previously mentioned did show `ESTABLISHED` next to the said ip address.

So i checked on the output of `last`, and i didn't notice any other ip beside mine there...moreover, the different ip i saw on `lsof` output dissapeared after a couple of seconds.

To monitor the output of `lsof`, I'm using this:

```
watch -n 1 lsof -i -P -n
```

Example output of the aforementioned command would be:

```
sshd      935            user    4u  IPv4  25823      0t0  TCP XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XX->XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX (ESTABLISHED)
```

Where second part after `->` is the part that is mentioned here, the first part being the ip of the server itself.

Is this normal to not see any entry (beside my own/previous one) on `last` when other tools like `lsof` do show a connection being `ESTABLISHED`?

I'm already aware that one can delete the entry in `/var/log` so that it doesn't come up on `last` output,  but the ip mentioned was gone so fast (less than 10 seconds after being `ESTABLISHED` on `lsof` output) that i find it hard to believe it managed to login...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only root has access to `/var/log/secure` (Red Hat) or `/var/log/auth.log` (Debian). Go there and check the logs.

Also bear in mind that when someone attempts to SSH to your server, they will be required to authenticate. During the authentication process, TCP session is `ESTABLISHED`. The session will disappear soon after login failure. That is why you see `ESTABLISHED` sessions showing up and disappearing. This is a sign of SSH brute-force attempts.

You might also consider locking down your SSH server

Comment: Thanks! learned something new. I did install ufw and some other logging daemon that i check from time to time :)